# Connecting BLE peripheral to multiple apps running on single iPhone

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have connected BLE peripheral to app running in background.

In another app I call `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)` to retrieve a list of connected peripherals.

Then I call `connect(\_:options:)` as described in "Discussion" section from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518924-retrieveconnectedperipherals), but `centralManager(\_:didConnect:)` is never called.

I retain CBPeripheral object.

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion from both links https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518924-retrieveconnectedperipherals and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518766-connect .  "centralManager(*:didFailToConnect:error:)" is called instead of  "centralManager(*:didConnect:)" if BLE peripheral is already connected other App.